# MySQL - help for a performant query

Tags: mysql, performance, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table where I keep stored all the logins to my website. The structure is like:

```
TABLE users_logins

loginid INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
userid INT
iplogin VARCHAR(15)
logindate datetime
```

Now, I need a query to retrieve the number of users who did the FIRST login with the same IP. The result should be something like:

```
iplogin | numberofaccounts
```

where 'numberofaccounts' is, as I said previously, the number of users that did their first login with the same 'iplogin'.

The table has around 300k rows...so what I should do to get what I need with good performances?

Thanks,

L.

Comment: Define "good performance". With only 300k rows it really shouldn't matter than much unless you're using a 486 for a server.

Comment: How many different users (`distinct user_id`) are there in the table? And how many different ips?

Comment: @ypercube not too many, 35k more or less

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add a column for the first login ip in your user table. Then it's a simple

```
select count(*), firstip 
from users 
group by firstip
```

Comment: Ya, I agree with you Tyler and I was thinking about it already, but unfortunately edit the structures is not an option for now.

Answer (score 0):

Add these indexes:

```
alter table users_logins 
  add key (iplogin, userid, logindate),
  add key (userid, logindate);
```

Now demonstrate that you can do the query to get the earliest login for each user by finding the login where there is no other earlier login for the same user.

This is a common solution to get the greatest/earliest entry per user or whatever.

```
select t1.iplogin, count(*) as numberofaccounts 
from users_logins as t1 
left outer join users_logins as t2 
  on (t1.userid=t2.userid and t1.logindate > t2.logindate) 
where t2.userid is null 
group by iplogin\G
```

The indexes defined above help the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and the `GROUP BY`.

The EXPLAIN report shows that this is pretty well optimized. It makes use of indexes for both tables, and does not cause a temp table or filesort, which are frequently performance killers.

It does do an index-scan (`type: index`) which means it reads the entire index, but at least that's not a table-scan.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: iplogin
          key: iplogin
      key_len: 29
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t2
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: userid
          key: userid
      key_len: 5
          ref: test.t1.userid
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```